# Deploying node js and php on heroku

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, nginx, heroku

So basically i'm trying to deploy an app that has node js and php in it.
My node js file is not used to run the server, i'm using node js only for socket.io and mysql npm.
My app is working fine when i run it in xampp but when i deployed my app to heroku it is saying "Connection failed: No such file or directory"

Comment: share nginx conf, seems like you have not configured server properly

Answer (score 0):

> So basically i'm trying to deploy an app that has node js and php in it.

So you're deploying two apps then.

You should deploy the Node app as explained here:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

You should deploy the Node app as explained here:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#introduction

Your apps will most  likely need to communicate witch each other, in which case you will need to configure environment variables accordingly. It is possible that your apps do not need to communicate with each other directly, but e.g. use a common database or a queue service etc. You will need to configure both of those to use such a service if needed.

It's hard to provide any more details because you didn't explain anything about what they do, not to even mention any source code examples.